# Por nekonata kvanto, cxu oni uzu "kiu" aux "kiuj"?

Tags: correlatives, questions

Ofte kiam oni volas demandi pri personoj en iu situacio, oni ne scias cxu estas unu persono aux pluraj. Ekzemple:

- Kiu/Kiuj iros al la klubo hodiaux?

  - Mia kaj David iros.
- Kiun/Kiujn sxi helpas?

  - Sxi helpas siajn gepatrojn.
- Al kiu/kiuj vi sendis la raporton?

  - Mi sendis gxin al cxiuj estraranoj de la federacio.

Se oni ne konas la kvanton, cxu oni diru "kiu" aux "kiuj"?

Answer (score 6):

En tiaj okazoj oni uzas ĝenerale la singularon, ĉar la pluralo (kiel markita, pli specifa formo) implikus, ke oni ja scias, ke temas pri ia kvanto (>1) kaj volas nur ekscii, kiom ekzakte.